# Multiple inner joins failing in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

The following works if {string} is quoted out of the query but fails if I include it. So far having multiple inner join on most posts apparently works, practically not the case would appreciate any feedback with regards.

```
SELECT DISTINCT species_tbl.* FROM species_tbl     
inner join species_common_names_tbl 
        ON species_tbl.id = species_common_names_tbl.species_id      
{
inner join species_synonyms_tbl ON species_tbl.id = species_synonyms_tbl.species_id
}    
WHERE
LOWER(species_tbl.keywords) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
LOWER(species_common_names_tbl.common_name) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%')
{ 
OR 
LOWER(species_synonyms_tbl.syn_genus) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
LOWER(species_synonyms_tbl.syn_sub_genus_name) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
LOWER(species_synonyms_tbl.syn_species_epithet) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') 
}
```

Ok did some testing and noticed that if species_synonyms_tbl table is not related to species_tbl table it will not return results so its binding on the fact to expect a relational id present

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `species_common_names_tbl` (
  `cn_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `species_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `common_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cn_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


INSERT INTO `species_common_names_tbl` (`cn_id`, `species_id`, `common_name`, `language`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Plain Rain Frog', 'English');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `species_synonyms_tbl` (
  `syn_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `species_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `syn_genus` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `syn_sub_genus_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `syn_species_epithet` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`syn_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `species_synonyms_tbl` (`syn_id`, `species_id`, `syn_genus`, `syn_sub_genus_name`, `syn_species_epithet`) VALUES
(1, 2, 'test', 'test', 'test');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `species_tbl` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keywords` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `species_tbl` (`id`, `keywords`) VALUES
(1, 'TEst');
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say that the query "fails", do you mean that it returns an error when you try to execute it, or that it executes but does not return the data you expect?

Comment: I think the data in species_synonyms_tbl causes failure in query. Otherwise your query is all correct. Please post some sample data.

Comment: The query returns nothing
I double checked the column names and they are correct

Comment: There is no error returning and am running the query from command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are doing inner joins to both the `species_common_names_tbl`  and `species_synonyms_tbl` tables, so you would have to have matching records on both tables - the only record in the data provided on the synonyms table was for species 2.

Try changing the joins to outer joins, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT species_tbl.* FROM species_tbl     
left join species_common_names_tbl 
        ON species_tbl.id = species_common_names_tbl.species_id      
left join species_synonyms_tbl ON species_tbl.id = species_synonyms_tbl.species_id
WHERE LOWER(species_tbl.keywords) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
      LOWER(species_common_names_tbl.common_name) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
      LOWER(species_synonyms_tbl.syn_genus) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
      LOWER(species_synonyms_tbl.syn_sub_genus_name) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
      LOWER(species_synonyms_tbl.syn_species_epithet) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%')
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99f0b/2).

EDIT, following confirmation of performance issues - the following appears to perform better against larger datasets:

```
SELECT DISTINCT species_tbl.* FROM species_tbl     
left join (select distinct species_id from species_common_names_tbl 
           where LOWER(common_name) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%')) scn
        ON species_tbl.id = scn.species_id      
left join (select distinct species_id from species_synonyms_tbl 
           where LOWER(syn_genus) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
                 LOWER(syn_sub_genus_name) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
                 LOWER(syn_species_epithet) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') ) ss
        ON species_tbl.id = ss.species_id
WHERE LOWER(species_tbl.keywords) LIKE LOWER('%Plain Rain Frog%') OR 
      scn.species_id is not null OR 
      ss.species_id is not null
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99f0b/4).

Comment: It works perfectly on one record but when I attempt to run it against 180 000 rows it takes a long time to return results. I quit after two minutes

Comment: @MarkWatson: The following *may* perform better against a larger dataset: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99f0b/4

Comment: @MarkWatson: You're welcome - I've added the alternative form of the query to my answer.